# I am trying to prepare a XElement with glyphicon "&#xAE;" with <sup> tag but in out put I am getting "&amp;#xAE;" how should I prevent it

Tags: c#, .net, c#-5.0

```
new XElement("sup", "&#xAE;");
```

when generating XHTML I am getting my XHTML like

Output:

```xml
<sup>&amp;#xAE;</sup>
```

Expected:

```xml
<sup>&#xAE;</sup>
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/01/21/writing-entity-references-using-linq-to-xml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new XElement("sup", "\xAE");
```

`XElement` already escapes it's content.

Comment: Thank you but now i am getting direct Registerd sign i want my output only in <sup>&#xAE</sup>